# Mp3 tags keep resetting

Tags: mediaserver, mp3-tag, permissions

I've got a ch3snas media server where I store all my mp3's on and I use Rhythmbox to play the files on my computer. I can adjust the info fine, no warnings but when I log back in the next time the information will have reset itself.

My mount setup in fstab:

```
//192.168.1.67/volume_1/Media/Music /media/Music cifs rw,exec,auto,username=daniel4ing,password=********,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Another issue I have is when I try to play the music files on my xbox 360. Where the information seems to be different then what I've tried to fill in and what I actually see when loading the files into Rhythmbox.

I've been trying a lot of different things over the last few years and this is a problem I just can't seem to fix and it's driving me crazy! I've tried editing with pretty much every single editor around.

So my guess is that I'm doing something wrong while mounting but it seems to be working fine for all my other media files like photos and movies.

Answer (score 2):

The DNS323 suffers from this server side DFS bug but it is possible to work around it.

In the samba config file on the nas, add the following line under ;[ global ]

```
msdfs root = no
client lanman auth = yes
```

and use the following rule in the /etc/fstab

```
//x.x.x.x/dir /home/username/mountdir cifs uid=myuser,workgroup=myworkgroup,username=xxxx,password=xxxx,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,n odfs,rw,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```